# Valgrind shows wrong version

Tags: valgrind

I downloaded Valgrind 3.10.1 and ran:

./configure
make
make install

However when I run valgrind --version, it shows 3.7.0.

What other ways can I check for the version? and what need to do to install latest valgrind 3.10.1 version

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the directory where you installed it (typically `/usr/local/bin`) is in your `PATH` before the directory containing the version that came with the OS (typically `/usr/bin`).  Then enter `hash -r` (bash) or `rehash` (zsh, tcsh) to tell your shell to rebuild its hash table that keeps track of where commands are located.